# Why does a capacitor in an AC circuit allow a lamp to glow continuously

Tags: electric-circuits

How does the capacitor allow the lamp to glow continuously, but would not do so if the circuit was DC.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reactance of a capacitor varies with respect to the frequency of the signal, AC has a finite positive frequency, but DC has a frequency of zero. Higher the frequency lesser the Reactance, Hence A Capacitor allows AC to pass through, but Blocks DC

Answer (score 3):

Notice

We know that the reactance of a capacitor is given as $$\color{blue}{R_c=\frac{1}{2\pi fC}}$$
Where, $C$ is electric capacitance & $f$ is the frequency of source

For an A.C. source, frequency, $\color{red}{f>0}\implies \color{blue}{R_c=\frac{1}{2\pi fC}>0}$ which means that a capacitor offers a constant resistance in A.C. circuit i.e. it allows the lamp to glow continuously

For a D.C. source, frequency, $\color{red}{f=0}\implies \color{blue}{R_c=\frac{1}{2\pi fC}\to \infty}$ which means that a capacitor offers infinite resistance in D.C. circuit i.e. it behaves as an open circuit (i.e. zero electric current) thus the lamp does not glow when capacitor connected in series with it (lamp).